# API in R & Ravelry

Tags: r, api, httr

I'm trying to use the Ravelry API to do some data analysis and I'm having difficulties.

I'm modeling my code after [this link](https://datasock.wordpress.com/2015/08/03/knitting-data-1-about-ravelry-api-connection) but I'm afraid this blog *may* have been written before there were different kinds of permissions on the Ravelry API.

I have a OAuth 1.0a API with a text file with my username, key, and secret

```
library(httr)
 
# user_rav.txt contains API username and password 
credentials <- readLines("user_rav.txt")
names(credentials) <- c("user","access_key","secret_key")
 
OpenConnection <- function(credentials){
  # Args: login info for the Ravelry API
  # Returns oauth token
  # Open connection to Ravelry API and return token
  reqURL <- "https://www.ravelry.com/oauth/request_token"
  accessURL <- "https://www.ravelry.com/oauth/access_token"
  authURL <- "https://www.ravelry.com/oauth/authorize"
   
  ravelry.app <- oauth_app("ravelry", key=credentials["access_key"], 
                           secret=credentials["secret_key"])
  ravelry.urls <- oauth_endpoint(reqURL, authURL, accessURL)
   
  return(oauth1.0_token(ravelry.urls, ravelry.app))
}
 
# Quick test of API connection by getting connected user info
TestConnection <- function(ravelry.token) {
  # Arg: API token
  # Returns name of the user connected with this token
  test <- GET("https://api.ravelry.com/current_user.json", 
              config=config("token"=ravelry.token)) 
  print(content(test)$user$username)
}
 
ravelry.token <- OpenConnection(credentials)
```

The last line, "`ravelry.token <- OpenConnection(credentials)`" produces this error:

```
 Error in init_oauth1.0(self$endpoint, self$app, permission = self$params$permission,  : 
  Internal Server Error (HTTP 500).
```

I've googled this error and, if you can believe it, there were only four hits. two weren't avaliable and the others were specific to an R package with the API that i'm not using.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I apologize. It was something as simple as the column heads in the credential file that needed to be edited.

Comment: Is it something where the solution will be helpful to others? If so, you should include it as a full answer. If not, you could consider the question a typo/not reproducible